# MP3 codec for WAV files

Tags: c++, windows, encoding, mp3

Wav files support different encodings, including mp3. Is there a C/C++ library that would produce mp3-encoded wav files from uncompressed wav? If not, what would be the best place to start to implement one?

Comment: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Container_format_(digital)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

1. The best way indead to use Lame (if you do not afraid patent issues). You can use the both sources for lame and lame_enc.dll. Using the lame_enc.dll is more easier.
   As for RIFF-WAV container: it is simply to create RIFF-WAV files according to RIFF-WAV specification.
2. There are another possibilities. For example using ACM codecs.

But in any case you should be capable to prepend sound stream with RIFF-WAV header. This can be done manaully (I think the simplest way) or by using some free library (it seems libsnd is capable to do this).

Comment: Actually, libsnd is quite explicit about not supporting MP3.

Comment: You sould distinguish support of audio stream format and file types (containers). There is no need to use allinone tool for producing RIFF-WAV MP3 files. You need: 1) a MP3 encoding engine (lame, ACM codec, DirectShow filter); 2) ability to add RIFF-WAV header to MP3 stream. For item 2 you can start from converting pure MP3 files to RIFF-WAV MP3 files.
See:
MPEGLAYER3WAVEFORMAT (MSDN)
RIFF-WAV specification (e.g. http://www.sonicspot.com/guide/wavefiles.html)
http://a-gamyl.hp.infoseek.co.jp/Clang/dgwriff/driff.cpp
http://www.koders.com/cpp/fid1163D7D7C554A5DD192C098EE9918D8B8AD8C618.aspx

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked : http://lame.sourceforge.net/

Comment: Unfortunately LAME produces MP3s in a MPEG container, not a RIFF container.

Comment: This is the first place I checked, thanks. It does not seem to be able to create wav files, like Ignacio said.